# Is there a way to inject constants into a Cython module from the command line?

Tags: python, cython

I want to embed configuration secrets (eg access keys) within a module compiled with Cython. These values should not be easily accessible from the compiled code and isolated from the actual source code. Is there a way of injecting this values from a different source than the main Python code (like a comand line option to cython or the c compiler)?

NB: I don't want to have an own Cython module just containing the access keys, because the access key can be easily found than.

Comment: Have you considered passing the constants as environment variables?

Comment: This would be OK at compile time. But not at run time

Comment: How about reading a binary key file?

Comment: If you have your access key compiled into your cython module (even encoded) near code which decodes/evaluates this key, then it will not take long to exctract the code from the binary.

Comment: User configuration should be provided by user, not hardcoded anywhere in code regardless of how it is hardcoded. Typically this is done by reading environment variables or by use of a configuration file. Neither of those have anything to do with Cython specifically and there are many examples how to do both with Python. All the Cython code needs is to have those values passed in via some external method.

Comment: @mai: This is basically what I do. I just need a way to (somehow externally to the rest of the  source code) inject the decode key.

Comment: @danny: I don't want this decoded data  easily accessible to the end user (because it goes into an embedded system and grants access to some cloud services). And I want it to be easily replaceable at compile time (so not in the normal source code). That I why I want to "bake" it into a Cython compiled code component.

Comment: I think what you need is an API authorization to your cloud service end points, where users manage their own credentials. That should be a hardware agnostic solution.

Comment: 'Baking' authentication data into compiled code *does* make it easily accessible to the end user. Your own proposal does not fit your requirements. An external file can easily be set to not be readable by users but readable by the program that needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preface:  THIS ISN'T SECURE AND YOU SHOULD NOT DO THIS TO HIDE CREDENTIALS.  *Anyone* with access to the binary will be able to dump the credentials out, and if they have the source (as you imply in the comments) it will be particularly easy.

That said, to answer the general question since cython files are compiled, the C pre-processor can be used to inject text, via the `-D` command-line flags.

Cython

```
# file.pyx
cdef extern from "header.h":
    cdef char* ARG

def f():
    return ARG
```

C header

```
# header.h
// empty, ARG will be inserted by preprocessor
```

Setuptools

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

ext = [Extension('file', ['file.pyx'], 
                 extra_compile_args=[f'-DARG=\\"{os.environ.get("ARG")}\\"'])]

setup(name='test', ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

In action

```
$ set ARG=THING
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
$ python
>>> import file
>>> file.f()
b'THING'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an injection mechanism, because you correctly assume that whatever is stored in the files accessible to the user will be extracted.

This definitely means that whatever way of *passing* the key material to the user code you choose, the key will be MITM-ed and exfiltrated. Yes, *the user-accessible code should never access the key.*

This is, of course, a solved problem. Use an API that accepts a challenge from your cloud service, and optionally user input ("password", etc), and returns a temporary authorization token. The token should expire soon enough to make session stealing impractical. The re-authorization process should repeat periodically, as long as the user is using the access.

This is how e.g. SSH works. You can safely hide the SSH key using the OS permissions, or a hardware token (see U2F). You can also try to use U2F with GPG; some cloud services may support U2F natively.

By now you surely remember the idea that security cannot be bolted onto an existing solution, but must be built into it form the start. You might need to rethink a wider swath of your app with security in mind, and come up with proper authorization mechanics. I don't know the specifics of your problem, so I cannot guess a specific approach.

Comment: I would prefer to get an answer to my question (how to inject that value). An authorization API has the same problem. How do I make sure that I only authorize our client code? Probably some form of challenge/response, and this also needs a key. Nearly all mobile apps (with a cloud component) eventually work that way: They hide a authorization key somewhere in the app code. Of course there are ways to get to that, but it is definitely more difficult (especially for an average user) than a plain text config file with the value.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "injecting". Why won't you just open a local file and read it from there? You have a contradiction in the requirements: you need to make the key available to the code, but require that "These values should not be easily accessible from the compiled code". You can isolate it form the _source_ code, of course. What is your threat model?

Comment: Because that file will contain the key. I want the key information tied to the executable  (embedded in lots of code)  so that getting to the information requires at least building and/or debugging of the binary. The user might have access to the normal source code. I could for example use JINJA2 as pre processor of the source before Cython, but this  will make building and debugging (without Cython) more complicated.